# Corrupted LUKS2 /home partition

Tags: fedora, partition, windows, luks, corruption

My `/dev/sdc` drive got corrupted by a dual boot windows missclick. I must have corrupted the partition table as far as I know. As most fora suggest I used `testdisk` to analyse and rewrite the GPT and It looks good for the boot part.

```
fdisk -l:
Device     Boot     Start       End   Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sdc1  *         2048    411647    409600  200M  6 FAT16
/dev/sdc2          411648   2508799   2097152    1G 83 Linux
/dev/sdc3         2508800 158756863 156248064 74.5G 83 Linux
/dev/sdc4       158756864 250066943  91310080 43.6G  5 Extended
/dev/sdc5       221263872 236888063  15624192  7.5G 82 Linux swap
```

Problem is I still only get in the fedora emergency mode. Now testdisk told me:

```
The following partition can't be recovered:
     Partition               Start        End    Size in sectors
>  Linux                 9882  72 47 266137 104 28 4116738573

[ Continue ]
LUKS 2 (Data size unknown), 2107 GB / 1963 GiB
```

I know that I encrypted my `/home` partition (size 29,8 GB) with LUKS2, so this makes sense. GParted also lists my partitions as following:

```
Partition   | File System | Size      | Flags
/dev/sdc1 | fat16           |  200MB | boot
/dev/sdc2 | ext4            |  1GB     | 
/dev/sdc3 | ext4            | 74.5 GB | 
/dev/sdc4 | extended     | 43.5 GB |
> unallocated | unallocated | 29.8GB |
   /dev/sdc5 |  linux-swap |
   unallocated | unallocated | 6.2GB |
```

So together `sdc1/` was `/boot/efi`, `sdc2/` `/boot`, `sdc3/` `/root`, `sdc4/ /home`, `sdc5/ /swap`.

Now some people suggest to find the LUKS Header with hexdump but i have no idea how to work with this. I get some lines which contain LUKS on most partitions. If needed I can provide the output of

```
hexdump -C /dev/sdcX | grep LUKS
```

Well and if I check if any of these partition are valid LUKS partitions with

```
cryptsetup -v luksDump /dev/sdcX
```

I only get

```
Device /dev/sdc3 is not a valid LUKS device
```

But I am really unsure about this part.

Here is some more Information provided by fsck:

```
fsck /dev/sdc1
fsck from util-linux 2.33
fsck.fat 3.0.28 (2015-05-16)
/dev/sdc1: 37 files, 5035/51145 clusters

fsck /dev/sdc2
fsck from util-linux 2.33
e2fsck 1.45.2 (27-May-2019)
/dev/sdc2: clean, 388/65536 files, 70988/262144 blocks

fsck /dev/sdc3
fsck from util-linux 2.33
e2fsck 1.45.2 (27-May-2019)
/dev/sdc3: clean, 595074/4890624 files, 6764082/19531008 blocks

fsck /dev/sdc4
fsck from util-linux 2.33
e2fsck 1.45.2 (27-May-2019)
/sbin/e2fsck: Attempt to read block from filesystem resulted in short read while trying to open /dev/sdc4
Could this be a zero-length partition?

root@PartedMagic:~/Desktop#  fsck /dev/sdc5
fsck from util-linux 2.33
```

and the /etc/fstab:

```
UUID=c6fe887e-f999-4a98-aa9a-2c0ae6255419 /                       ext4    defaults        1 1
UUID=d853e689-5d9b-4f75-9700-5c71e6ee3d2d /boot                   ext4    defaults        1 2
UUID=C1D1-DDF3          /boot/efi               vfat    umask=0077,shortname=winnt 0 2
/dev/mapper/luks-7916b37f-48fd-45bd-9d27-9a28ee45dfab /home                   ext4    defaults,x-systemd.device-timeout=0 1 2
UUID=9866cba6-4a1e-4bd0-a764-e86f8ceb63d9 none                    swap    defaults        0 0
/dev/md126  /run/media/MAIN     ext4    defaults    0 0
```

I have a `dd` clone of my drive just in case. I don't know what I should do next. I am very glad for all kinds of suggestions.

**Thanks alot! :)**

Comment: Do you have a backup of your LUKS header? If not... I hope you didn't have any important data in that partition.

Comment: Well not too important luckly.. lesson learnd i guess.. Always backup the LUKS header !!!